# Azure pipeline output variables task.setvariable is not assigning any value to variable

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to execute terraform script to create ec2 and using output variables concept I want to get the ec2 public ip and assign it to a variable and pass that to another task. But I see that output variables using bash or script is not working in azure pipeline yml. I am using ubuntu agent.

```
- script: COMMAND=$(cat terraform.tfstate | grep 'public_ip"' | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d'"' -f2) && echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ec2ip;]$COMMAND" && echo $ec2ip
```

But I see no value is printing. Not sure whether the task.setvarible is working or not.
Need some help to fix this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot echo the new variable's value in the same script task. The new variable set by statement `task.setvariable` is only available in the subsequent tasks.

You can add a subsequent script task to echo variable `ec2ip`. And you retrieve its value by wrapping it in `$()` (ie.`$(ec2ip)`). Please check document [Define vairables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) for more information.

```
- script: COMMAND=$(cat terraform.tfstate | grep 'public_ip"' | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d'"' -f2) && echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ec2ip;]$COMMAND" 


- script: echo "$(ec2ip)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created new task and able to get the value.

Comment: Thanks so much! Where is this behaviour specified in the documentation?

Comment: I didn't see this behavior in the documentation. You saved me an hour.